Overestimation in OLS using uncorrelated features
I am using OLS to build the best linear model to explain the variance of (predict) $Y$ using two features $X_1$ and $X_2$ with following two considerations:

$X_1$ and $X_2$ do not exhibit multicollinearity, i.e., $\rho(X_1, X_2) \approx 0 $
Both $X_1$ and $X_2$ explain the overlapping portion of variance in $Y$, i.e.,
$\beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2$ overestimates $Y$ 
where, $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are outcome of two separate linear regressions: $Y = \beta_1 X_1 + \epsilon$ and $Y = \beta_2 X_2 + \epsilon$

What is the best technical term to explain above scenario in #2? Would following be the best approach to address this situation:
Step-1: Estimate $\beta_1$ using OLS $Y = \beta_1 X_1 + \epsilon$ 
Step-2: Estimate error as $\hat{Y_1} = Y - \beta_1 X_1$ 
Step-3: Estimate $\beta_2$ using OLS $\hat{Y_1} = \beta_2 X_2 + \epsilon$ 
Think about generalizing this to $n$ features $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$
Background:
One can think of $X_2$ being some non-linear transformation of $X_1$ with little additional information content to explain $Y$

Why not just use multiple regression?

Thanks @PeterFlom     (a) I have more data for $Y$, $X_1$ than for $Y$, $X_1$, $X_2$. So multiple regression becomes tricky as more number of features ($X_n$) all having different sample size such that common/intersection sample size being much smaller.     (b) Given $X_1$ and $X_2$ are uncorrelated, $\beta$’s estimated through stagewise regression should be same as those from multiple regression.

Have you considered multiple imputation?

Thanks again @PeterFlom. Correct me if I am wrong: multiple Imputation is suitable when there is relatively small portion of missing data. However, in my case intersection of $X_1$, $X_2$, ..., $X_n$, can result in a very small sample for any given $X_i$ compared to the rest.

It isn't so much that MI is bad when there is quite a bit of missing data, as that nothing is good in that situation.   If you look at several simple regressions, then you will have very different data sets, and can't really compare the results.

Please add  new info as an edit to the post! not only in comments. Comments on this site are ephemeral, can easily be overlooked, and can be deleted

Can you not do a bias correction from the first stage? If you know it is biased, then why not debias with another term?
